# To find min. value in a list in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, list, max, distance, min

I have a list of specific class.
In this list , a position class is included.
And that position class includes X and Y coordinates.
I have Current Coordinates and the coordinates in list .
I want to calculate the distance for each item in List and find which item has minimal distance.
Here is my code :

```
  For Each item As ITEMX In xHandle.ItemList

        Dim CurrX As Integer = txt_TrainX.Text
        Dim CurrY As Integer = txt_TrainY.Text
        Dim NextX As Integer = item.Position.x
        Dim NextY As Integer = item.Position.y

        Dim distance As Integer = DistanceBetween(CurrX, CurrY, NextX, NextY)


    Next
```

so distance is the distance between my coordinates and the item.
I calculate it for each item in list but how do i find the minimal one ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a variable for the minimal value, and check it against each value in the loop.

You should parse the text from the controls outside the loop, it's a waste to do that over and over again inside the loop. You should also turn on strict mode so that you don't do implicit conversions that shouldn't be implicit.

```
Dim minimal As Nullable(Of Integer) = Nothing

Dim CurrX As Integer = Int32.Parse(txt_TrainX.Text)
Dim CurrY As Integer = Int32.Parse(txt_TrainY.Text)

For Each item As ITEMX In xHandle.ItemList

  Dim NextX As Integer = item.Position.x
  Dim NextY As Integer = item.Position.y

  Dim distance As Integer = DistanceBetween(CurrX, CurrY, NextX, NextY)

  If Not minimal.HasValue or distance < minimal.Value Then
    minimal.Value = distance
  End If

Next
```

Comment: Thanks for asnwers.I think they will help.

Answer (score 3):

Using Linq in VB.NET:

```
Dim CurrX As Integer = txt_TrainX.Text
Dim CurrY As Integer = txt_TrainY.Text

Dim NearestITEM = xHandle.ItemList.Min (Function(i) DistanceBetween(CurrX, CurrY, i.Position.x, i.Position.y));
```

for some information and samples abount Linq in VB.NET see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vbasic/bb688088

Answer (score 1):

Building on @Yahia's LINQ answer a bit to both get the item and the item's distance.

```
Dim CurrX = CInt(txt_TrainX.Text)
Dim CurrY = CInt(txt_TrainY.Text)

Dim itemsWithDistance = (From item in xHandle.ItemList
                         Select New With {.Item = item, 
                                          .Distance = DistanceBetween(CurrX, CurrY, item.Position.x, item.Position.y)}).ToList()

' At this point you have a list of an anonymous type that includes the original items (`.Item`) and their distances (`.Distance`).
' To get the one with the smallest distance you can do.
Dim nearestItem = itemsWithDistance.Min(Function(i) i.Distance)

' Then to see what that distance was, you can
Console.WriteLine(nearestItem.Distance) 

' or you can access nearestItem.Item to get at the source item.
```